# Как добавить в одну колонну SQLite несколько значений?

Tags: python, sqlite3

Допустим, есть колонка с названием id и нужно туда поместить 2 переменные, но когда пытаюсь внести вторую, система не запоминает.
Код, если нужен:

```
user_id = [(0002)]
users_id = [(01)]

def table_os():

    con = sqlite3.connect('/py/kess.sqlite')

    cur = con.cursor()

    cur.execute('INSERT INTO userlevent (id) VALUES (?)', (user_id))

    con.commit()
    cur.close()
    con.close()
```

После того как я внес user_id, меняю на users_id, запускаю но выводит все-же user_id.

Comment: `cur.execute('INSERT INTO userlevent (id) VALUES (?)', (user_id))` тут можно просто `user_id`, т.е. `cur.execute('INSERT INTO userlevent (id) VALUES (?)', user_id)`, т.к. в `user_id` находится список

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы список добавить в запрос можно использовать цикл, например:

```
import sqlite3

def table_os():
    users_id = [1, 2, 3]

    con = sqlite3.connect('/py/kess.sqlite')
    cur = con.cursor()

    for user_id in users_id:
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO userlevent (id) VALUES (?)', [user_id])

    con.commit()
    cur.close()
    con.close()
```

А лучше использовать не `execute`, а [executemany](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany):

```
import sqlite3

def table_os():
    # Список кортежей на один элемент
    users_id = [(1,), (2,), (3,)]
    # Или список списков: [[1], [2], [3]]

    con = sqlite3.connect('/py/kess.sqlite')
    cur = con.cursor()

    cur.executemany('INSERT INTO userlevent (id) VALUES (?)', users_id)

    con.commit()
    cur.close()
    con.close()
```